# Error changing solr schema

Tags: solr

I'm very very new to solr. I launched a Bitnami VMI on Amazon AWS just this morning.

After some googling I found how to use putty to ssh to the box, use filezilla to sftp files etc. I wanted to change the fields in the schema, so i downloaded the schema.xml file from collecction1, modified it and re-uploaded it.

After which, I ran a reload command, but am now getting an error.

collection1: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException:org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr/collection1/data/index/write.lock: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/bitnami/apache-solr/solr/collection1/data/index/write.lock (Permission denied)

I can see that the write.lock file is present on the filesystem, so I'm not sure why im getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Al

Comment: Is the write.lock file owned by the same user that Solr runs under?

Comment: Hi fiskfisk - sorry for the delayed response. Your comment sent me in the right direction - it was because I had executed chown to give access for FTP, and had not changed it back to solr which is the account solr runs under. Thanks

Comment: Err, how do i mark a comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: by changing a permission for data folder its working now :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the write.lock file is owned by the same user as Solr runs under.